# Get AngularJS scope variable (inside javascript) defined in resolve/promise

Tags: angularjs

I am defining my rootScope variable in routes using resolve/promise as I want this variable to be available before the controller gets executed.

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'test.html',
            controller: 'test',
            resolve: {
                ccApp: ['$q','$rootScope','$location',function($q,$rootScope,$location) {

                    var defer = $q.defer();
                    $rootScope.testString = "This is just a test data";

                    defer.resolve($rootScope.testString);
                    return defer.promise;
                }]
            }
        });
```

And I am trying to access this in my javascript as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >        
    var testString = $('[ng-controller="test"]').scope().testString;
</script>
```

I didn't use rootScope inside the javascript as rootScope is not defined in the javascript.

But this is not working. My doubt is whether I can use the controller here. Otherwise, how can I get this value inside javascript. Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add the $timeout will give the enough time to get the scope available for the javascript to read the value.

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'test.html',
            controller: 'test',
            resolve: {
                ccApp: ['$q','$rootScope','$location','$timeout',function($q,$rootScope,$location,$timeout) {

                    var defer = $q.defer();
                    $rootScope.testString = "This is just a test data";

                    $timeout(function() {
                          defer.resolve($rootScope.testString);
                    }
                    return defer.promise;
                }]
            }
        });
```

And this is working now.